# Aggregation of text elements per id over the last 10 or 30 days in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, aggregate, filtering

I have a dataset that looks like the following:

```
id <-c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
date <- c("2022-11-01 22:22:01","2022-11-01 22:22:01","2022-11-18 12:48:16","2022-11-19 20:57:44","2022-11-19 20:57:44","2022-11-28 13:33:28","2022-11-29 19:24:28",
         "2022-11-29 19:24:28","2022-11-01 10:02:47","2022-11-01 10:02:47","2022-11-08 02:48:37","2022-11-08 02:48:37","2022-11-17 17:35:17","2022-11-17 17:35:17",
         "2022-11-22 12:30:20","2022-11-22 12:30:20","2022-11-30 09:47:45")
type <- c("aaa", "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "aaa", "ccc", "aaa", "bbb", "bbb", "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "bbb", "aaa", "ccc", "bbb", "ddd")
o_number <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 11, NA, NA, 12, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 13, NA, NA, 14)
total <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 200, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 300, 0, 0, 400)
```

```
df <- data.table(id,date,type, o_number, total)
```

I would like to summarize all the text elements of the column "type" for the last 10 or 30 days by the column "id" everywhere I have an "o_number". The soulution should consider the "date" column. This means that a time range can be selected (e.g. 10 or 30 days).

The result for a periode of 30 days should look like this:

```
    id                date type o_number total                        type_over_last_30days_per_id
 1:  1 2022-11-01 22:22:01  aaa       NA     0                                                    
 2:  1 2022-11-01 22:22:01  aaa       NA     0                                                    
 3:  1 2022-11-18 12:48:16  bbb       NA     0                                                    
 4:  1 2022-11-19 20:57:44  ccc       NA     0                                                    
 5:  1 2022-11-19 20:57:44  aaa       11   100                         aaa > aaa > bbb > ccc > aaa
 6:  1 2022-11-28 13:33:28  ccc       NA     0                                                    
 7:  1 2022-11-29 19:24:28  aaa       NA     0                                                    
 8:  1 2022-11-29 19:24:28  bbb       12   200       aaa > aaa > bbb > ccc > aaa > ccc > aaa > bbb
 9:  2 2022-11-01 10:02:47  bbb       NA     0                                                    
10:  2 2022-11-01 10:02:47  aaa       NA     0                                                    
11:  2 2022-11-08 02:48:37  bbb       NA     0                                                    
12:  2 2022-11-08 02:48:37  ccc       NA     0                                                    
13:  2 2022-11-17 17:35:17  bbb       NA     0                                                    
14:  2 2022-11-17 17:35:17  aaa       13   300                   bbb > aaa > bbb > ccc > bbb > aaa
15:  2 2022-11-22 12:30:20  ccc       NA     0                                                    
16:  2 2022-11-22 12:30:20  bbb       NA     0                                                    
17:  2 2022-11-30 09:47:45  ddd       14   400 bbb > aaa > bbb > ccc > bbb > aaa > ccc > bbb > ddd
```

I tried a lot of variations of the following code (in this case i used 30 days but i should also work with 10 days):

```
 df %>%
       filter(date >= (date - days(30)) &  (date - days(30)) <= date)  %>% 
       dplyr::group_by(id, o_number)  %>%
       dplyr::summarise(type_over_last_30days_per_id = paste(type, collapse = ">"))
```

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure there's a better way to do this but I gave this a shot.

I added a grp_id column to return an index relative to each group.
Then use an ifelse statement to return all values in type when o_number is not NA, concatenated by ">".

Next you need to subset the extra values by the grp_id value to get the correct number of type changes.

#### Updated Answer

I made some updates to handle any date range that you want. With the caveat that the range will start on the minimum date per id. If you want to start by a different date then subset `df` first.

Additionally, the data you provided won't work as is if the date range is 10 days. Since for both ids, o_number is NA within the 10 day period starting from the minimum date.

For this I built a little function that can handle your df and includes an option to set your date range.

Hope this helps!

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

df <- data.table(id,date,type, o_number, total)
df[, date := as.POSIXct(date)] # convert to datetime set to local timezone

# Generate type changes per id over a specified number of days.
type_change_summary = function(d, days) {
  # Subset by number of days for each id
  df_sub = d[date <= min(date) %m+% days(days), .SD, by = .(id)]
  
  # Err if there are only NAs
  if(all(is.na(df_sub$o_number))) {
    stop("o_number does not include any values")
  }
  
  # This returns all values of type per group when o_number != NA
  df_sub[, grp_id := rowid(id)]
  df_sub[, rng := ifelse(!is.na(o_number), vapply(.SD, paste0, collapse = ">", FUN.VALUE = character(1L)), NA), by = .(id), .SDcols = c("type")]
  
  # Generate col name
  col = paste0("type_over_last_",days,"days_per_id")
  
  # Apply by rows over grp_id and rng then subset the initial character string in rng by the grp_id value.
  df_sub[rng != "NA", 
   (col) := apply(.SD, 1, function(x) {
     # x is a named vector here
      paste0(unlist(strsplit(x["rng"], ">"))[1:as.integer(x["grp_id"])], collapse = " > ")
    }), 
    by = .I, 
    .SDcols = c("rng", "grp_id")][, `:=` (grp_id = NULL, rng = NULL)][]
  
  return(df_sub)
}
```

```
type_change_summary(df, 20) # set to 20 days.

   id                date type o_number total      type_over_last_20days_per_id
 1:  1 2022-11-01 22:22:01  aaa       NA     0                              <NA>
 2:  1 2022-11-01 22:22:01  aaa       NA     0                              <NA>
 3:  1 2022-11-18 12:48:16  bbb       NA     0                              <NA>
 4:  1 2022-11-19 20:57:44  ccc       NA     0                              <NA>
 5:  1 2022-11-19 20:57:44  aaa       11   100       aaa > aaa > bbb > ccc > aaa
 6:  2 2022-11-01 10:02:47  bbb       NA     0                              <NA>
 7:  2 2022-11-01 10:02:47  aaa       NA     0                              <NA>
 8:  2 2022-11-08 02:48:37  bbb       NA     0                              <NA>
 9:  2 2022-11-08 02:48:37  ccc       NA     0                              <NA>
10:  2 2022-11-17 17:35:17  bbb       NA     0                              <NA>
11:  2 2022-11-17 17:35:17  aaa       13   300 bbb > aaa > bbb > ccc > bbb > aaa
```

**Example by subsetting the data to "2022-11-17" and using 10 days.**

```
df_2 = df[date >= as_date("2022-11-17")]
type_change_summary(df_2, 10)

   id                date type o_number total type_over_last_10days_per_id
1:  1 2022-11-18 12:48:16  bbb       NA     0                         <NA>
2:  1 2022-11-19 20:57:44  ccc       NA     0                         <NA>
3:  1 2022-11-19 20:57:44  aaa       11   100              bbb > ccc > aaa
4:  2 2022-11-17 17:35:17  bbb       NA     0                         <NA>
5:  2 2022-11-17 17:35:17  aaa       13   300                    bbb > aaa
6:  2 2022-11-22 12:30:20  ccc       NA     0                         <NA>
7:  2 2022-11-22 12:30:20  bbb       NA     0                         <NA>
```

#### Old Answer Below

```
library(data.table)

# Get row id per group
df[, grp_id := rowid(id)]

# This returns all values of type per group when o_number 1= NA
df[, last_30 := ifelse(!is.na(o_number), vapply(.SD, paste0, collapse = ">", FUN.VALUE = character(1L)), NA), by = .(id), .SDcols = c("type")][]

# Apply by rows over grp_id and last_30 then subset the initial character string in last_30 by the grp id value.
df[last_30 != "NA", 
   type_over_last_30days_per_id := apply(.SD, 1, function(x) {
     # x is a named vector here
      paste0(unlist(strsplit(x["last_30"], ">"))[1:as.integer(x["grp_id"])], collapse = " > ")
  }), 
  by = .I, 
  .SDcols = c("last_30", "grp_id")][, `:=` (grp_id = NULL, last_30 = NULL)]
```

```
> df
    id                date type o_number total                        type_over_last_30days_per_id
 1:  1 2022-11-01 22:22:01  aaa       NA     0                                                <NA>
 2:  1 2022-11-01 22:22:01  aaa       NA     0                                                <NA>
 3:  1 2022-11-18 12:48:16  bbb       NA     0                                                <NA>
 4:  1 2022-11-19 20:57:44  ccc       NA     0                                                <NA>
 5:  1 2022-11-19 20:57:44  aaa       11   100                         aaa > aaa > bbb > ccc > aaa
 6:  1 2022-11-28 13:33:28  ccc       NA     0                                                <NA>
 7:  1 2022-11-29 19:24:28  aaa       NA     0                                                <NA>
 8:  1 2022-11-29 19:24:28  bbb       12   200       aaa > aaa > bbb > ccc > aaa > ccc > aaa > bbb
 9:  2 2022-11-01 10:02:47  bbb       NA     0                                                <NA>
10:  2 2022-11-01 10:02:47  aaa       NA     0                                                <NA>
11:  2 2022-11-08 02:48:37  bbb       NA     0                                                <NA>
12:  2 2022-11-08 02:48:37  ccc       NA     0                                                <NA>
13:  2 2022-11-17 17:35:17  bbb       NA     0                                                <NA>
14:  2 2022-11-17 17:35:17  aaa       13   300                   bbb > aaa > bbb > ccc > bbb > aaa
15:  2 2022-11-22 12:30:20  ccc       NA     0                                                <NA>
16:  2 2022-11-22 12:30:20  bbb       NA     0                                                <NA>
17:  2 2022-11-30 09:47:45  ddd       14   400 bbb > aaa > bbb > ccc > bbb > aaa > ccc > bbb > ddd
```

Comment: Thank you! It’s an interesting approach but it doesn't solve the problem. However, it should consider the “date” column. This means that a time range of 10 days is also possible.

Comment: Can you update your example to show how my solution fails?

Comment: i updated the example. In your solution it's not possible to change the time range. It should work for different time ranges. Maybe you have an idea how to that?

Comment: @Markus please see my recent edits

Answer (score 0):

My approach is pretty similar to @Jamie answer, but more `dplyr` and `purrr`.

Input :

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
id <-c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
date <- c("2022-11-01 22:22:01","2022-11-01 22:22:01","2022-11-18 12:48:16","2022-11-19 20:57:44","2022-11-19 20:57:44","2022-11-28 13:33:28","2022-11-29 19:24:28",
          "2022-11-29 19:24:28","2022-11-01 10:02:47","2022-11-01 10:02:47","2022-11-08 02:48:37","2022-11-08 02:48:37","2022-11-17 17:35:17","2022-11-17 17:35:17",
          "2022-11-22 12:30:20","2022-11-22 12:30:20","2022-11-30 09:47:45")
type <- c("aaa", "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "aaa", "ccc", "aaa", "bbb", "bbb", "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "bbb", "aaa", "ccc", "bbb", "ddd")
o_number <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 11, NA, NA, 12, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 13, NA, NA, 14)
total <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 200, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 300, 0, 0, 400)
df <- data.table(id,date,type, o_number, total)
df=as.data.frame(df)
```

Then convert the date using `strptime` so you can control which date you want to consider

```
df$Date=strptime(x = df$date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
df=df%>%filter((Sys.time()-df$Date)<30)
```

Last step is playing with list of character that you split, collapse controlling the length of it so you have the right result

```
df=df%>%group_by(id)%>%mutate(merged=paste0(type,collapse = ">"),#for each id make the whole vector
rn=row_number())#Add row number so you can subset the whole vector accordingly

df=df%>%mutate(result=case_when(is.na(o_number)~NA_character_,#Put NA when there is no o_number
                                TRUE~map2_chr(.x = merged,.y = rn,.f = ~paste0(
str_split(.x,pattern =  ">",simplify = T)[1:.y],
collapse = ">"))))#Split, subset and collapse vectors on each line the has a o_number
```

In case you want to keep all rows at the end, just save rows of older date in a dataframe to remerge them at the end with the output dataframe using `bind_rows`